# How can I improve my function to work better?

Tags: function, common-lisp

I am coding a function where I need to create a new list by inserting a certain value into the list after position N.  Here is the code:

```
(DEFUN insertNth (L N insValue)
    (cond ((NULL L) NIL)
          ((NULL (CDR L)) (CONS (CAR L) (insValue)))
          (T (CONS (CAR L) (insertNth (CDR L) N insValue)))
    )    
)
```

When I try to test the code, I receive this error: *** - EVAL: undefined function INSVALUE.  Is there a step or a piece of the function I may be missing?

Comment: First, insValue is not a function, but (insValue) will try to evaluate it as such. I think you mean to say (list insValue). Then, have you thought about what is the expected result when n is bigger than the length of l? Another clue: look at the function nthcdr.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun insertNth (l N insValue &optional (acc '()) (counter 0))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        ((= N counter) (nconc (nreverse acc) (list insValue) l))
        (t (insertNth (cdr l) N insValue (cons (car l) acc) (1+ counter)))))
```

I took the destructive functions `nreverse` and `nconc` due to performance reasons.
Destructive functions here have no danger, but improve performance.
You can, however, use the non-destructive functions `reverse` and `append` instead which will be more familiar to you.